# Is it possible to pass a ng_model reference to a function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select box and an input which is dependent on said select box, rather then write the function 6 times ( as this relationship occurs 6 times) I would like to pass the inputs ng_model reference to the ng-Change function of the select box so that when the select box is changed the function can update the referenced model

### Update

this is What I currently have:

```
<select id="name_select" ng-model="name_model" ng-change="getAU_name(type_model,name_model)" ng-selected="name_model" ng-options="user.name as user.name for user in AU_model[type_model]"  required></select>
<input id="description_input" ng-model="description_model" disabled></input>


$scope.getAU_name = function (type, name) {
    $.each($scope.AU_model[type], function (index, value) {

        if (value.name == name || value.description === name) {
            console.log("name= " + value.name + " description= " + value.description);
            $scope.description_model= value.name;
        }

    });
```

But I have 6 seperate Relationships that do the same thing so I am trying to avoid having 6 versions of getAU_name just to set the `$scope.description_model`

basically I have 6 models, `description_model`, `description_model_2`...etc that I would like to set with the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the logic and you can definitely simplify a lot like this. You just need to pass `user` in the function instead of type_model and you don't need the loop in the controller at all.

You'd better create a `description` object to hold all 6 models.

```
<select id="name_select" ng-model="name_model" ng-change="getAU_name(user, name_model, 'model1')" ng-selected="name_model" ng-options="user.name as user.name for user in AU_model[type_model]"  required></select>
<input id="description_input" ng-model="description.model1" disabled></input>

$scope.getAU_name = function (user, name, model_name) {
    if (user.name == name || user.description === name) {
        description[model_name] = user.name;
    }
};
```

Comment: is that not just passing the value of stuff? Im looking for away to pass my model and then inside the `mychange(stuff){ stuff = someValue }`

Comment: @jonnieM You can't demonstrate your question properly so no one can understand. Paste your code and we will help you to polish it. And `stuff = someValue` makes no sense.

Comment: I have added code. in the context of your answer, `stuff = someValue ` makes complete sense, as somevalue is a value I'm assign to stuff which I am assuming you meant as the refference to the ng_model, I know this does work but I am looking to do something similar

Comment: @jonnieM Updated. Hope it helps.

Comment: that unfortunitly doesn't work as it just passes the value of description_model and not the reference

Comment: @jonnieM That is why I said your `stuff = someValue` makes no sense...... Updated.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to pass the mode; if that model is already in your $scope?

you can do something like this:

view:

```
<input ng-model="stuff" ... >
<a ng-click="mychange();">click</a>
```

controller:

```
$scope.mychange = function(){
  $scope.stuff = "newValue";
}
```

UPDATE:

im sorry now i see what you need, i think you should write a directive for this problem here is an example of something i did:

view:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events" data-testd> 
    <span>{{event.title}}</span>  
    <a ng-click="clicky(event)">click</a>      
</div>
```

js:

```
app.directive("testd", function() { 
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.clicky = function(event){
            event.title="yolo";             
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid explicitly referring to the scope variable as it will require a separate function for each of the relationships

Comment: updated,, see if thats what you need